# Retrieve all items in cache

Tags: c#, caching, memcached, enyim

I have recently got `Enyim Memcached` up and running and it is working great. Using the library I am able to store and retrieve items with no problem.

However, I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve all items from the cache.
I am aware that you are able to retrieve an item by its key:

```
  MemcachedClient client = new MemcachedClient()
  object o = client.Get("key");
```

But I can't seem to see a `GetAll()` or similar method, am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I want to elaborate on dasun's answer. He is correct that there is no way to get all keys out of standard memcached, however there are other flavors of memcached that allow you to do this through tap streams. You can do this if you use Membase server (If you just use cache buckets Membase is pretty much just memcached) or you can use the Membase branch of memcached which can be found here https://github.com/membase/memcached. The Membase branch is definitely safe to use and many of the top memcached contributors work for Membase (now Couchbase) and contribute stuff from this branch back to the main memcached branch.

On another note, the Enyim client doesn't support the tap API, but there are Java, C/C++, python, and ruby client that support tap. What you would do is a create a tap dump stream and this stream would send you all of the key value pairs memcached/Membase.

Answer (score 3):

No, You can't. Memchached is not designed for that purpose(Caching not meant to retrieve all item, which is pointless).

Comment: It does have a point if you want to remove a single item from a list of cached items....

Comment: It is often important to analyze the content of cache independent of one's ability to store and retrieve.

Comment: Though the accepted answer says I'm correct, Can anyone explain why i'm getting down vote for this?

Comment: You're getting downvoted because people do not like the answer, even though you are correct.

Comment: It's a harsh truth. One that kind of stinks because what if you want to migrate your data to some other cache engine?